# How to sort polygons without a depth buffer

Tags: 3d, rendering, software-rendering, sorting

Please help me getting understanding how did they sort polygons in old games from the eighties.

They did not use z-buffer or anything like this, thats for sure.

[image: Screenshot of green quad on top of a grey table]

Please look at the screenshot. How would one decide that the green surface should be drawn after the table polygons?

The center of the table surface is closer to the viewer from object center, closest vertex point of view. The green surface has the farthest Z. Oh, this big gray table is not split into smaller polygons.

How did they know to draw the green poly after the big gray table surface?

Comment: Can you tell us what game this is?

Comment: Hello, this particular one I made using picture from the Freescape engine, just for ilustration of this simple problem. It was developed for 8bit computers like Amstrad CPC or ZX Spectrum ;-)

Comment: In the forum thread [Space Station Oblivion (C64... or CPC/Spectrum) - WTF. SO many technical questions](http://www.pouet.net/topic.php?which=11910), I found an [alleged disassembled code from the game driller for Amiga](http://franck.charlet.pagesperso-orange.fr/temp/driller_src.zip) by the user hitchhikr (Franck Charlet). *I can't make head or tails of the asm code, perhaps somebody reading this can.*

Comment: I wonder how retrocomputing.stackexchange.com would tackle this question. In this site the emphasis is often on how could we do it, rather than how it was done, given that how it was done is often something that only the developer can fully answer, and we are more interested in helping people develop new games. With that said, cross posting is discouraged. Perhaps, you can leave here the question in terms of how it could be done, and ask there how it was done.

Answer (score 2):

In [interview](https://theeye.unblockit.pw/public/Books/retrowith.in/Retro%20Gamer%20-%20Issue%20No.%20141.pdf), Ian Andrew, founder of Incentive Software, designer and co-creator of Freescape along side his brother Chris, said:

> Each element was held within a bounding box which enabled the z-order to be completed with one check rather than the thousands involved for each pixel. And Chris used a unique sorting system which really enabled the game to become reality.
>
> (...)
>
> Memory restrictions and speed were the main problems. (...) There
> was no memory for z-buffering so the object sorting helped speed things up.
>
> (...)
>
> Memory was re-used wherever possible; for example, the back buffer, where the
> next screen image is constructed, was used during the calculations and object sorting before the drawing even started,

*Apparently they called this technique "box sorting" internally. I have not found more details on how that worked.*

---

What follows is my speculation on my part based on that simple description.

You could define a 3D bounding box for each object. Provided that you never allow bounding boxes to overlap in space, sorting these bounding boxes should be enough to decide the draw order.

To be clear, the following should not be allowed:

[image]

The algorithm I describe here, cannot handle that.

You could proceed to project to the view-port the coordinates of the bounding boxes, resulting in some 2D polygons. You could then intersect the 2D polygons from two objects to decide if you need bother to determinate the draw order between two object at all…

If you do, you got to check the depth of the objects at one of the points in the intersection of the 2D polygons, that is one of the points where they visually overlap. The depth for that point would be computed from the distance to the camera, for the other object you would need to solve the intersection of the ray with bounding box. That difference in depth should be enough to decide what object draw first.

*I suppose you would optimize this algorithm further.*

---

For the example case in the question, let us imagine some bounding boxes. I draw them in blue an purple below:

[image]

*Caveats: I have no idea if the green square has height, I have no idea if the table is one single bounding box.*

We can intersect the 2D polygons these bounding boxes made in 2D. And in doing so, we find that there there is visual overlap. I mark the visual overlap region in blue below:

[image]

While, yes, you would have used depth while projecting each point to 2D (in order to archive perspective), no comparison in depth is done. I repeat that this overlap is entirely visual. *By which I mean, it exists only in 2D, it is the intersection of 2D polygons.*

And thus you would have to compare depth at one of the points in the intersection. Market below, also in blue (added arrows for clarity):

[image]

And comparing depth at any of those points would result in the green shape being drawn on top of the table. *You only need to compare depth at one of those. Just one depth check (comparison).*

*Any point that belongs to an intersection of the 2D polygons that are the projections of the bounding boxes of the 3D objects will do, given that those bounding boxes do not intersect in 3D space.*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109795/discussion-on-answer-by-theraot-how-to-sort-polygons-without-a-depth-buffer).